# specifying quote level for email replies

Tags: html, email, formatting

What are the standards (are there even standards) or conventions for formatting email? Specifically, how do I specify quote levels in a way that email clients understand?

Just digging into a few emails, I'm noticing that apple mail seems to prepend quoted paragraphs with a `>`, is that the standard?

If I'm sending an html email, do I do the same?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia has a [good article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posting_style) about this in general. You'd probably be safe using the '>' prefix to indicate a level of quoting - it has a long history and I imagine most (maybe all) email clients will interpret it correctly.

If you're sending an HTML email, you can pretty much do whatever you like, but you can't control whether or not the recipient will view your email in HTML, or prefer to view plaintext version (or worse - they see the raw HTML). I recommend keeping it simple.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Wikipedia huh? I should have checked that.